# Which way is best when getting files off couple of document libraries

Tags: 2013, performance, query

**Scenairo**

Two document libraries (no folders just default settings only uploading files),

> Fruit Crate Document Library
>
> Fruit Document Library

Now I have a string with names of files....

```
string[] fileNeededNames = {"filea.docs", ....};
```

Now I need to check if `Fruit Crate Document Library` has item with title in string array above, then if it has then i will check it's extension - if its extension is `.doc` then I will download it, if it doesn't have extension as `.doc` then I have to query Fruit Document Library which may have "`.doc"` version of file but saved with title of Fruit Crate's item's "id",

This is what I am doing yet,

```
        using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite(site))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = siteCol.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.GetList(site + libraryURL);
                if (list is SPDocumentLibrary)
                {
                    SPDocumentLibrary library = list as SPDocumentLibrary;
                    SPListItemCollection results = library.GetItems();
                    List<string> getFruitItems = new List<string>();
                    foreach (SPListItem item in results)
                    {
                        string fileName = item.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
                        if (fileNames.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(item.File.Name.ToUpperInvariant()))
                        {
                            if (fileName.EndsWith(".DOC"))
                            {
                                aFile.SaveDocumentToDisk(inputFolder, item.ID.ToString() + ".doc", item.File.OpenBinary());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                getFruitItems.Add(item.ID.ToString() + ".doc");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    SPList docList = web.GetList(site + docLibraryURL);
                    SPDocumentLibrary docLibrary = docList as SPDocumentLibrary;
                    SPListItemCollection docResults = docLibrary.GetItems();
                    foreach (SPListItem docItem in docResults)
                    {
                        if (getFruitItems.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(docItem.File.Name.ToUpperInvariant()))
                        {
                                aFile.SaveDocumentToDisk(inputFolder, docItem.ID.ToString() + ".doc", docItem.File.OpenBinary());
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are getting all items and iterating it to find whether the file already exists or not.

Instead of that you can use CAML query. Just create a query with all the filenames and use that to find the file already exists or not.

Something like

```
<Query>
   <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                <Value Type='Text'>filea.doc</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                <Value Type='Text'>fileb.doc</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
   </Where>    
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='ID' />
   <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
   <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
</ViewFields>
```

Now you can use the query which only returns minimal List Items. The follow the same logic what you have.

**Dynamic query**

```
string template = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq>";
string query = "<Query><Where><Or>";
string []fileNames = ... Popluated From WebService
foreach(string fileName in fileNames) {
    string f = string.Format(template, fileName);
    query += f;
}
query += "</Or></Where></Query>";
```

The above is only a pseudo code, you should adjust it accordingly.

Comment: No hard coding, receiving file names from web services

Comment: Yes in that case also you can form the query dynamically. See my update